# How to send highest matplotlib scatter plot c-values to front?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, matplotlib, scatter-plot

I have a pandas dataframe of 3 columns (x, y, z) which I plot using a scatter plot with z-variable assigned to the c-value, with the resulting [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MLi91.jpg)

Variables x, y, and z are all continuous real data and z != f(x,y). I'm unable to provide the actual data sample.

As you can see the points overlap, and highest values are hidden from view.

I would like this plot to display the highest (red) points on top of the lowest (blue points) to produce an intensity plot similar to [this](https://www.google.com/url?sa=i&source=images&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwi_vb_B8c3jAhVPqxoKHbTOBagQjRx6BAgBEAU&url=%2Furl%3Fsa%3Di%26source%3Dimages%26cd%3D%26ved%3D%26url%3Dhttp%253A%252F%252Fsupport.prosig.com%252F2015%252F03%252F03%252Fcreating-order-plots-using-the-dats-rotating-machinery-software%252Fscreenshot-2015-02-10-13-46-45%252F%26psig%3DAOvVaw2D58XhVRrHBmMHsi81LxrV%26ust%3D1564068968127387&psig=AOvVaw2D58XhVRrHBmMHsi81LxrV&ust=1564068968127387)

I assume this is achieved by somehow controlling the plot order of z, and I have tried sorting the dataframe by the z-variable with no success.

I would appreciate some method for the existing chart or a suggestion for a new chart to make this possible.

Comment: Can you include your current code and it's output?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try with this

```py
df = pd.DataFrame(data={'x': [0.2, 0.21, 0.22],
                        'y': [0.2, 0.21, 0.22],
                        'z': [1.8, 2, 3]})

df.plot.scatter('x','y',c='z', s=5000)
```

Then with this

```py
df.sort_values('z', ascending=False, inplace=True)

df.plot.scatter('x','y',c='z', s=5000)
```

The z order is reversed between the two

Comment: Thanks Simon this is exactly what I needed! The  "inplace=True" argument solved the issue.